# Sportmanship badge changed?

Tags: discussion, badges

I've just noticed that I don't have the Sportmanship badge any more. I may be wrong but I think I had that already. Has this badge changed? I think it used to need 15 upvotes but now seems to need 100.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Am I wrong?

Yes, you are... It was always 100.

I took a look at our revision history - the number 100 was there 5 years ago.

Comment: Ok, I don't know why but I was sure I've got that one already but I'm clearly mistaken... Thank you.

Comment: A source may be *[List of all badges with full descriptions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397)*.